# Google Mail Access URL

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, javascript

I want to display my Google Apps mails on my website homepage, in a google gadget. So, I want to fetch all mails of my google apps account using javaScript. Is there any way to access mails ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Google has a Gmail gadget for your iGoogle page available at this link - http://www.google.com/ig/adde?moduleurl=builtin_gmail.xml&source=imag

you can also search for gadgets with the term "[check email](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?q=check+email&type=gadgets)"

Be warned, that there might be some unscrupulous / malicious code out there.

Ideally, if it's only notification you want, use official notifiers from service providers or an offline client. Preferably, one that connects securely.

Comment: That is for Gmail. Sorry, for that I forget to mention regarding Gadget of personal mail domain.

Comment: Is your personal domain powered by Google Apps?

Comment: Yes. It is powered by Google Apps.

Comment: It is not only the notification. But, I want to show last 10 mails gadget (with From : Subject & on clicking, it will open Domail mail) on the Homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't support any special API for the GMail. All you can do is to enable [POP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10350)/[IMAP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75725) from the settings and taking it over from there it whatever language you want.

Comment: Can I use MIME ?

Comment: @Sarang MIME is not a protocol.

Comment: Ya. But, however, I need not to enable POP/IMAP. Some iGoogle Gadgets fetched gmail & show on iGOogle Page. Then how do we do this with our personal domain mails without enabling POP/Imap ?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply embed http://m.gmail.com in an iframe. Gmail also offers RSS feeds, but only for unread mail and it's a password-protected feed.